# Conditionally show buttons in DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

How to show buttons in cells of DataGridView if, for example, column A has value?

```
private void dgv_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    var dgv = (DataGridView)sender;
    if (dgv.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "btn")
    {
        var hide= dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[dgv.Columns["A"].Index].Value is DBNull;
        var cell = dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[dgv.Columns["B"].Index];
        if (hide)
        {
            //cell.Value = null;
            //cell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
            cell.Visible = false; // This dosn't work
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way to do this is to bind to the Item_DataBound (I believe that's what it's called) on the grid view.  Then check the column to see if it contains the value you need.  Then you can hide specific controls in the cell like this (using most of your code in your post):

```
cell.Controls[0].Visible = false;
```

Comment: This was too beautiful to be true.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom `DataGridView` and `CustomDataGridViewColumn` for it and assign the property to set `visible` and `invisible` particular cell button. here is an example that demonstrate how to create custom column for datagridview. 
http://www.codemag.com/Article/0707061
otherwise it is not possible to make any cell button directly either visible or invisible.

Answer (score -1):

You need to cast button containing cell to [DataGridViewButtonCell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewbuttoncell%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The `Cell` can be cast to this class if it is `Button Cell`.

Use this:

```
var cell = dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[dgv.Columns["B"].Index] as DataGridViewButtonCell;
cell.Visible = false;
```